# extracting substring after specific word in excel

Tags: excel-formula

How to extract text string after specific word or selected word in excel

ishue type: some text.
Solution: NA#
Remarks: NA

I want to extract text after solution:

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to include the word solution in your output you can use the following formula, if your text value is in cell A1

```
=MID(A1,(FIND("Solution:",A1)+10),LEN(A1))
```

The +10 will remove the value Solution: from the export.

If you want to include the word solution you can use

```
=MID(A1,(FIND("Solution:",A1)),LEN(A1))
```

The find element will find the word you are looking for, while the mid element will look for the element within the string. Finally the len function will extract everything after the selected word, to the length of the original string